# Weird ping, and I have no idea what cases it

Tags: windows-10, internet, ping, gaming

If I'm playing a game with EU based server (currently playing POE, UK server), majority of the time, I get 66-68, and 83-85 ping.

(Looking at task manger) if only the POE is using Internet I get 66-68, if a number of other applications (like 1 to 5) (like Chrome, discord etc.) use 0.1 Mbps (most likely much less, since it rounds to 0.1) I get 83-85 ping (always).

They keep using Internet on and off making my ping go 67,84,66,85,68,83 etc.

Also even though nothing changes on task manager I sometimes get spikes that can give me 400 to 600 ping. It sometimes also goes to ~50 ping, and ~100 ping, but only rarely.

My main question is why it in the first place does it only go to those pings, and never any other ping Like 70, 90, or 110? And my second is if any one can have an idea why I get the large spikes? Since its quite effective in getting me killed.

Using mobile Internet, Sweden, telia. Am ether way going to switch to fiber soon (hopefully this year, if the idiot people setting up the fiber can finish any time soon, been about a year now since they began in my area), bahnhof, so it could fix it.

All drivers are up to date, and has been a problem for some time now, so updates, and re-installs has not helped in the slightest.

Down 8,57 Mbit/s, and up 12,66 Mbit/s

Image of ingame ping (lightshot)

https://prnt.sc/k2ls0n
https://prnt.sc/k2lzwh

Dump of my processes
https://pastebin.com/8geYxzz6

Comment: If it really goes to 60-69, 80-89, and 100-109 frequently, but *never* 70-79, 90-99, or ≥110, that’s weird.  More likely it’s a probability distribution thing, when some combination(s) of factors make 60-69 probable, some combination(s) of factors make 80-89 probable, etc., and you just get the other values so rarely that you don’t notice them. Spikes could be caused by factors outside your network, like sporadic congestion at the ISP or of the mobile frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

Is it happening only on PoE? Have you tried using a different server? (Frankfurt for example)
While playing PoE I had these insane spikes as well (especially after the big update.) But it calmed with time. Took a week or so.